# Why does using the Google APIs Python client in appengine with GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB result in ResponseNotReady

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-python-client

The code will work just fine in the SDK, but on Google AppEngine, it explodes:

```
  File "./oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
  File "./googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 197, in build
  File "./oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
  File "./oauth2client/client.py", line 563, in new_request
  File "./httplib2/__init__.py", line 1608, in request
  File "./httplib2/__init__.py", line 1350, in _request
  File "./httplib2/__init__.py", line 1306, in _conn_request
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/python_std_lib/httplib.py", line 1033, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady()
ResponseNotReady
```

This only happens when GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB is on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the Google API library is not aware of this and blindly uses a socket to connect to https://www.googleapis.com, which is not allowed. Further, the actual code hides the real error, which a permission denied on trying to create a socket.

I'm not aware of any workaround, except disabling sockets for httplib, or not using the provided libraries, but using a requests based one and installing an adapter that uses urlfetch for these domains.

Answer (score 0):

Socket connections are only available for paid apps. Have you setup billing for your app?

From the [documentation on sockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/):

*Sockets are only available for paid apps, and traffic from sockets is billed as outgoing bandwidth.*

Why are you trying to use sockets anyway?

Comment: Because I need to upload and download more than 10MiB. And, yes. It is a paid app, from further down: Private, broadcast, multicast, and Google IP ranges are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @gcbirzan's answer. Below would be steps to make it work :-

- Commenting `GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB: True` if it's set in `app.yaml` under `env_variables`
- For requests installing `requests_toolbelt` using `pip install -t lib/ requests_toolbelt`(make sure you have requests version >= 2.10.0 for this to work)
- Include below lines in `main.py` to enable requests_toolbelt adapter
  `import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
  requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()`

Above steps should be enough to solve this issue.