# How to use service account with private key file and impersonated user (DWD) in Google App Engine and local development server?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-app-engine-python

Application: Google App Engine Python standard environment

Purpose: Access Google APIs (not Cloud APIs) through the `google-api-python-client`, e.g. [Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/), by using a **service account and impersonate a user**, because the app is supposed to act on behalf of this user. (2-legged auth, the user won't be asked to grant access)

I've got a setup running in production environment, but it runs only on the local development server (`dev_appserver.py`) for testing if a certain environment variable would be removed. I'm looking for a solution that would work without adding/removing the environment variable.

The service account was created for the app and configured with domain-wide delegation DWD in Admin Console. Sheets API is turned on for this project.

Of the many quick-starts, samples, and references available, it was only after reading the [Google Auth Library for Python documentation](http://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html) (`google-auth`) that I've noticed the missing parts (an environment variable and the SSL library) and finally got the code running on production.

The app code will use the private key JSON file that was downloaded from Cloud Console IAM.

**requirements.txt**

```
# as suggested by almost all docs, but this isn't everything we need:
google-api-python-client==1.6.5
google-auth==1.4.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
```

**app.yaml**

```
env_variables:
  # enable socket support of paid app, needed for OAuth2 service-accounts
  # see google-auth documentation, v1.4.1, chapter 1.2.4
  GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : true
# some other stuff
libraries:
# to make HTTPS calls to other services, needed for OAuth2 service-accounts
# see google-auth documentation, v1.4.1, chapter 1.2.4
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

**appengine_config.py** (partial sample for Sheets API v4 access)

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
APP_ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "service-account-private-key.json"
import googleapiclient.discovery
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
# impersonate as user@example.com (G Suite domain account)
credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@example.com')
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
# until here, the code works in production and local dev server
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId="DOC-ID-HERE", range="A1:C5").execute()
# execute() will work only in production,
# on local dev, it will raise an ResponseNotReady exception
```

**traceback**

```
ERROR    2018-03-05 16:32:03,183 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 351, in __getattr__
    self._update_configs()
  File "/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 287, in _update_configs
    self._registry.initialize()
  File "/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 160, in initialize
    import_func(self._modname)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/appengine_config.py", line 143, in <module>
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/googleapiclient/http.py", line 839, in execute
    method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/googleapiclient/http.py", line 166, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 187, in request
    self._request, method, uri, request_headers)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/google/auth/credentials.py", line 121, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 322, in refresh
    request, self._token_uri, assertion)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 145, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 106, in _token_endpoint_request
    method='POST', url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 116, in __call__
    url, method=method, body=body, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1659, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1399, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Users/user/git/project/gae/_lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1355, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/Users/user/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/python_std_lib/httplib.py", line 1121, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady()
```

I have figured out that if I delete `GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB` from app.yaml's `env_variables` list, the code will work on local development server (but not in production anymore).

Am I doing something wrong here? Could I use the same code (maybe with a small switch) for both environments, without manually adding/removing the variable from app.yaml?

Comment: Look At this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31066877/9015852 as you are trying to use a Google API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Purpose: Access **Google APIs** (not Cloud APIs) through the google-api-python-client, e.g. Sheets API v4, ….*

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions_if_lang_is_java_java_7_runtime_only_endif) they explain that:

> Private, broadcast, multicast, and Google IP ranges (except those whitelisted below), are blocked:
>
> - Google Public DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 2001:4860:4860::8888, 2001:4860:4860::8844 port 53
> - Gmail SMTPS: smtp.gmail.com port 465 and 587
> - Gmail POP3S: pop.gmail.com port 995
> - Gmail IMAPS: imap.gmail.com port 993

2. *I have figured out that if I delete `GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB` from app.yaml's `env_variables` list, the code will work on local development server (but not in production anymore).*

This is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#using_sockets_with_the_development_server):

> **Using sockets with the development server**
>
> You can run and test code
> using sockets on the development server, without using any special
> command line parameters.

Finally, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066876/why-does-using-the-google-apis-python-client-in-appengine-with-gae-use-sockets-h) and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31066877/9015852) describe a similar scenario.

Hope this helps you :-)